# Shell Script Argument without value

Tags: linux, bash, getopts

I'm creating a very simple sh file to do something, but I want to pass an argument without a value, for example:

```
./fuim -l
```

But I receive the following message:

```
./fuim: option requires an argument -- l
```

If I pass a random value, like `./fuim -l 1`, it works perfectly. How can I do that?

Here's what I have so far:

```
while getopts e:f:l:h OPT
do
    case "$OPT" in
        h) print_help ;;
        e) EXT=$OPTARG ;;
        f) PROJECT_FOLDER=$OPTARG ;;
        l) LIST_FILES=1 ;;
        ?) print_help ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "$EXT" ] || [ -z "$PROJECT_FOLDER" ]; then
    print_help
fi
```

Comment: So it's a mandatory argument option.  Optional argument options use two colons (:) instead of one (as in `getopts e:f:l::h`), look the manual of getopts(1) for that, as there's some side effects when you use optional argument options.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When using `getopts`, putting `:` after an option character means that it requires an argument. So change `l:` to `l`, as in:

```
while getopts e:f:lh OPT
```

This makes it a boolean option, either it's there or it isn't.

Comment: Went through multiple blog, but no one has mentioned about the `:` behaviour. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Those must be pretty bad tutorials, as this is one of the most basic features.